# Is there a way to rank events per event record (ranking by row, not column) in Teradata?

Tags: teradata, ranking

I have a table with multiple columns related to events for each record. What I'm trying to do is rank each event within each record by date.

I've tried to transpose this in Excel but it doesn't like null values. In Teradata, I tried a case when statement, but there's too many columns to try this. Rank/dense rank are for columns I believe. Would the answer lie in cross joins?

For example the table looks something like this, but has alot more rows and columns:

```
Cust_number|Event_dte|Close_dte|Lst_Upte_Dte|
1          |2018-05  | 2018-09 | 2018-06    |
2          |2017-05  | 2018-09 | 2018-06    |            
3          |2018-01  | 2018-10 | 2018-06    |
4          |2015-05  | 2018-06 | 2017-09    |
5          |2018-05  | 2018-05 | 2018-10    |
```

The output should be:

```
Cust_number|Event_dte|Close_dte|Lst_Upte_Dte|
1          |1        | 3       | 2          |
2          |1        | 3       | 2          |            
3          |1        | 3       | 2          |
4          |1        | 2       | 2          |
5          |1        | 2       | 2          |
```

Comment: Case statements will be your best bet here, by a lot, I'd think.  Otherwise you'd basically have to un-pivot this,derive your ranks, and re-pivot.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround was to bring the table into Excel, transpose it, use a combination of ISNA and RANK while having it in ascending order, then reversing the transposition it and then re-import it into Teradata.